# Why whoami always returning "root"?

Tags: root, group, su, whoami

After a hack, a dedicated server always return "root" following `whoami` command. Even after a `sudo su myUser` > `whoami` return "root".

`myUser` exists on the server, because regarding [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180759/whoami-returns-root-how-do-i-set-myself-up-as-user) `passwd myUser` return `Changing password for myUser.`

Furthermore, when installing package on the server, rights are always set as `root:myUser`.

What are the paths, that could lead to a `whoami` always returning 'root' ?

Comment: What is myUser's UID?

Comment: The UID of "myUser" is `1000`. I have another user on this server, let's call it "mySecondUser" and UID is `10002`. The UID of "root" is `0`.

Comment: "After a hack" -- do you mean "after a creative workaround" or "after an unauthorized elevated access"? If the former, what changes were made? If the latter, perhaps it's time to burn it down & rebuild?

Comment: I mean an unauthorized elevated access... The changes made by the author are totaly unknow. However, our server serve lots of things, that are actually impossible (task force velocity) to migrate to cloud solutions or another dedicated server.

That's why I'm trying to see the differents paths that could lead to my issue...

Comment: I feel compelled, anyway, to point you to this SF Q/A: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be that the `whoami` binary was setuid `root`. You can check it with `stat $(which whoami)`. On my system it looks like this:

```
  File: /usr/bin/whoami
  Size: 30904           Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 1bh/27d Inode: 13918180    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

If it has setuid enabled it looks like this:

```
  File: /usr/bin/whoami
  Size: 30904           Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 1bh/27d Inode: 13918180    Links: 1
Access: (6755/-rwsr-sr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

The effect of this bit is that the binary is being run as its owner - and not as the user who starts it.

You can disable this setting by running `sudo chmod -s $(which whoami)`.

(But yeah, as many people already wrote in the comments, you probably should reinstall the machine completely.)

Comment: I think you get it right. I got `Change: 2020-03-05 18:07:25.500937072 +0100` that is not from us. Access is as follow : `Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`. After `sudo chmod -s $(which whoami)`, I got : `Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)`.

And the `whoami` resolve `myUser`. THANK YOU.

Comment: I think that that should not be a parenthetical at the end.  It should be the very first point in the answer.  The questioner's problems are far from over, and focussing on fixing the superficial output of `whoami` when someone has gone around modifying system binaries with superuser access is focussing upon the wrong thing.

Comment: Yes, of course.. But in order to analyze some things, this is a required step. Thank you for your help guys ! :)